# How do you pause and restart an animations in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I want to know how to pause and restart animations. I followed this code, but it's not working for me:

```
animRight = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.move_right1);
            animRight.setDuration(3000);
            mTv1.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
            mTv1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.hand);
            animRight.setAnimationListener(this);
            mTv1.startAnimation(animRight);

// override methods 

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
// when animations is finished 
 }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
// when animations is start
 }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
// when animations is repeated  
 }
```

Here I want to pause and restart the animation. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

> Animation do not have a pause method

From the API : [Package android.view.animation](http://www.androidjavadoc.com/1.0_r1/android/view/animation/package-summary.html)

Check out the comment on a way to [go about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864488/how-do-i-pause-frame-animation-using-animationdrawable).

Answer (score 0):

There is no pause method.You can go for implementing postDelayed.

Comment: i know pause method not avilable in animation , is there any other way to implement pause and restart