# Pausing animation on touch

Tags: android, multithreading, animation

Hi guys I am new to Animation. I have an Animation spinning around and would like it to pause as I touch and hold the screen. I need it to pause so that when the touch is released it will resume from the same position. I can do the touch listener easily, but can't figure out a way to pause the animation.

I have read about using a separate thread and pausing it, but surely that isn't the correct/most common way of doing it?

Thanks always appreciate the help!

Comment: @jono you got your answer ....then post this  here also ?

Answer (score 0):

Try referring to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864488/how-do-i-pause-frame-animation-using-animationdrawable/2864503#2864503). It states that...

> Animations do not have a pause method.

Comment: I know that but there is ways around it and im just wondering what people find the best

Comment: Note that the linked question did receive a [**positive answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7840895/192373).