# How to pause animation along with the activity?

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, resume

need all your suggestions for this.

I am implementing some basic animations in my activity . Now i am in a situation where i want to pause the activity along with the animations when i started the activity the animation also starts from that pause position.How can i achieve this?

sample code::

```
TranslateAnimation mAnimation=new TranslateAnimation(20, 875, 0, 50);
mAnimation.setDuration(3000);
mAnimation.setAnimationListener(this);
mRlCurAnswer.startAnimation(mAnimation);
```

Thanks..

Comment: Can you show how you are showing the Animation

Comment: its hand animation towards right side of the screen when user pause the activity the hand will stop where it is right now.and starts from that position when resumes the activity.

Comment: What is the minSdkversion for your app? You can call `cancel()` if your version is 2.2 and above.

Comment: is it frame animation or tween animation ? or you play any swf please show your code over here

Comment: Well show code would be better.

Comment: @user77777777 i am working on honeycomb...If cancel the animation we cant get it back where we stopped the animation...i want to resume the activity form the animation where it stopped previously

Comment: it is not small code to put here....I am applying some basic animations not much...for example when hand starts from left to right on the middle of the animation if i pause the activity the hand will be stopped there itself and started from there if i resume the activity

Comment: Hope these links will give a lead [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2864488/how-do-i-pause-frame-animation-using-animationdrawable/7840895#7840895) and [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20330628/android-pause-animation)