# Pause and Resume Translate Animation

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I am using Translate Animation for moving an `ImageView`. I am using this code:

```
TranslateAnimation set1 = new TranslateAnimation(-4, 10, -110, 0);
        set1.setDuration(3000);
        TranslateAnimation set2 = new TranslateAnimation(10, -3, 0, 115);
        set2.setDuration(3000);
        set2.setStartOffset(2200);
        TranslateAnimation set3 = new TranslateAnimation(-3, -20, 0, -100);
        set3.setDuration(3000);
        set3.setStartOffset(4500);
        TranslateAnimation set4 = new TranslateAnimation(0, 13, 0, -120);
        set4.setDuration(3000);
        set4.setStartOffset(6500);

        animSet.addAnimation(set1);
        animSet.addAnimation(set2);
        animSet.addAnimation(set3);
        animSet.addAnimation(set4);

        animSet.setFillAfter(true);
```

After creating a set of animations, I apply them on the `ImageView` like this:

```
image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
        image.startAnimation(animSet);
```

Everything is working fine, but **I cannot pause the animation and resume on button click**.

How can I do that?

I tried everything, but didn't succeed. Any idea how to do this?

Please help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After searching for a time i found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7840895/1250370) and check is this working for Translate Animation or not and after some modification this is working for your animation too.!

See modified code below:

```
public class TranslateAnim extends TranslateAnimation{

    public TranslateAnim(float fromXDelta, float toXDelta, float fromYDelta,
            float toYDelta) {
        super(fromXDelta, toXDelta, fromYDelta, toYDelta);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private long mElapsedAtPause=0;
    private boolean mPaused=false;

    @Override
    public boolean getTransformation(long currentTime, Transformation outTransformation) {
        if(mPaused && mElapsedAtPause==0) {
            mElapsedAtPause=currentTime-getStartTime();
        }
        if(mPaused)
            setStartTime(currentTime-mElapsedAtPause);
        return super.getTransformation(currentTime, outTransformation);
    }

    public void pause() {
        mElapsedAtPause=0;
        mPaused=true;
    }

    public void resume() {
        mPaused=false;
    }
}
```

I'll only change class name, extends class name and constructor of this class.

you can use it like:

```
TranslateAnim set1, set2, set3, set4; // objects of TranslateAnim Class
    
set1 = new TranslateAnim(-4, 10, -110, 0); // initialize all objects like this way
    
animSet.addAnimation(set1); // add all animation objests in your animation set as you do before
            
animSet.setFillAfter(true);
```

and after start your animation you have only call pause and resume methods.
Thanks to Johan for share his code with us.

Hope this solve your problem. :)

Comment: Can we load animation from XML?

Comment: Can we set the position of view after using on pause. I mean, suppose I use pause method in between and then I want to apply the new animation at the paused position. Is it possible?

Answer (score -1):

You can also do like this: <s>а можно еще так:</s>

```
public class MyTranslateAnimation extends TranslateAnimation {

    private long mTimePause, mTimeTotal;
    private boolean mPause;


    public MyTranslateAnimation(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

        super(context, attrs);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean getTransformation(long currentTime, Transformation outTransformation) {
        updateTime(currentTime);
        return super.getTransformation(mTimeTotal - mTimePause, outTransformation);
    }

    private void updateTime(long currentTime) {
        long dt = currentTime - mTimeTotal;
        mTimeTotal += dt;
        if (mPause) {
            mTimePause += dt;
        }
    }

    public void pause() {
        mPause = true;
    }

    public void resume() {
        mPause = false;
    }

}
```

To create an animation from an XML, you can create your own `AnimationUtils` subclass, like this: <s>для создания анимации из XML можно сделать свой AnimationUtils:</s>

```
public class MyAnimationUtils {

    public static Animation loadAnimation(Context context, int id) throws Resources.NotFoundException {

        XmlResourceParser parser = null;
        try {
            parser = context.getResources().getAnimation(id);
            return createAnimationFromXml(context, parser);
        } catch (XmlPullParserException ex) {
            Resources.NotFoundException rnf = new Resources.NotFoundException("Can't load animation resource ID #0x" + Integer.toHexString(id));
            rnf.initCause(ex);
            throw rnf;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Resources.NotFoundException rnf = new Resources.NotFoundException("Can't load animation resource ID #0x" + Integer.toHexString(id));
            rnf.initCause(ex);
            throw rnf;
        } finally {
            if (parser != null) parser.close();
        }

    }

    private static Animation createAnimationFromXml(Context c, XmlPullParser parser) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {

        return createAnimationFromXml(c, parser, null, Xml.asAttributeSet(parser));

    }

    private static Animation createAnimationFromXml(Context c, XmlPullParser parser, AnimationSet parent, AttributeSet attrs) throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {

        Animation anim = null;

        // Make sure we are on a start tag.
        int type;
        int depth = parser.getDepth();

        while (((type=parser.next()) != XmlPullParser.END_TAG || parser.getDepth() > depth)
                && type != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

            if (type != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                continue;
            }

            String  name = parser.getName();

            if (name.equals("set")) {
                anim = new AnimationSet(c, attrs);
                createAnimationFromXml(c, parser, (AnimationSet)anim, attrs);
            } else if (name.equals("alpha")) {
                anim = new AlphaAnimation(c, attrs);
            } else if (name.equals("scale")) {
                anim = new ScaleAnimation(c, attrs);
            }  else if (name.equals("rotate")) {
                anim = new RotateAnimation(c, attrs);
            }  else if (name.equals("translate")) {
                //anim = new TranslateAnimation(c, attrs);
                anim = new MyTranslateAnimation(c, attrs); // отредактировали только эту строчку, остальное взяли как было
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException("Unknown animation name: " + parser.getName());
            }

            if (parent != null) {
                parent.addAnimation(anim);
            }
        }

        return anim;

    }

}
```

And then you build the animation like this: <s>и вот так создаем анимацию:</s>

```
MyTranslateAnimation cloud1 = (MyTranslateAnimation) MyAnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.main_cloud1);
```

Hope this helps. <s>Пользуйтесь на здоровье!</s>