# how can I pause a translate animation with a button?

Tags: android

I got a translate animation with a background music and i want to pause it with a button and then resume it with another button (animation and music the same time), how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is just two separate questions...

- Pausing animations: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10028575/832776
- Pausing music (depends on the method, but this is assuming you're using the media player): https://stackoverflow.com/a/7634606/832776