# how to pause activity when dialog box is open in xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

i have a animation runing on my activity, a logo that is rotating....

i call function onBackPressed() that show alert dialogBox "are you sure you want to exit ?" there are two buttons "Yes" or "No"

.....i want my activity pause so that the logo donot rotate while dialog box is open...

here's my code

```
public override void OnBackPressed()
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder exit = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        exit.SetMessage("Are you sure You want to Exit");
        exit.SetCancelable(false);
        exit.SetPositiveButton("yes", (object sender, DialogClickEventArgs e) =>
         {
             this.Finish();
         });
        exit.SetNegativeButton("No", (object sender, DialogClickEventArgs e) =>
         {
         });
        exit.Show();}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hold a reference to your animation, and call pause on it when showing the dialog :

```
public override void OnBackPressed()
{
    AlertDialog.Builder exit = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    exit.SetMessage("Are you sure You want to Exit");
    exit.SetCancelable(false);
    exit.SetPositiveButton("yes", (object sender, DialogClickEventArgs e) =>
     {
         this.Finish();
     });
    exit.SetNegativeButton("No", (object sender, DialogClickEventArgs e) =>
     {
       myAnimation.resume();
     });
    myAnimation.pause();
    exit.Show();
}
```

You can use this good example/answer to know how to pause and resume an animation : https://stackoverflow.com/a/10028575/4706693
OR use the simple pause and resume from the `Animator` class if that's what you're using

Answer (score 0):

You `can't` pause the activity but the activity's `lifecycle` method `OnPause()` will be called when you show your dialog.

You can just `stop/pause` the animation in the `OnPause()` method of your acitivty.

Comment: `public override void OnBackPressed()

    {

       OnPause();

        AlertDialog.Builder exit = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        exit.SetMessage("Are you sure You want to Exit");

        exit.SetCancelable(false);

        exit.SetPositiveButton("yes", (object sender, DialogClickEventArgs e) =>

         {

             this.Finish();

         });

        exit.SetNegativeButton("No", (object sender, DialogClickEventArgs e) =>

         {

         });

        exit.Show();

       }


protected override void OnPause(){

base.OnPause();

}`

Comment: You don't call methods like OnPause(), android will call them when required